# Build crashing on launch

Tags: google-play-games

I implemented the google play game services to my game for leaderboards and achievements, my game builds normally, but when I try to launch it on android, it crashes before the unity splash logo shows, logcat gives me this:

```
com.FarSouth.RocketJumper/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity
 03-03 16:48:59.617  2993  2993 D ActivityManager: starting Active launch
 03-03 16:48:59.648  2993  5385 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN typ=null flg=0x10200000 cmp=ComponentInfo{com.FarSouth.RocketJumper/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}} from uid 10077
 03-03 16:48:59.665  2993  3769 I ActivityManager: DSS on for com.FarSouth.RocketJumper and scale is 0.75
 03-03 16:48:59.702  2993  3628 D ActivityManager: isScaleDownAnimationEnabled() : false
 03-03 16:48:59.702  2993  3628 D ActivityManager: applyOptionsLocked, ANIM_CUSTOM_SCALE_UP, x : 803, y : 879, isHomeItem : false
 03-03 16:48:59.702  2993  3628 D ActivityManager: applyOptionsLocked, ANIM_CUSTOM_SCALE_UP, task.getRootActivity() : ActivityRecord{f3e35f2 u0 com.FarSouth.RocketJumper/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t21599}, task.getTaskToReturnTo() : 1
 03-03 16:48:59.702  2993  3628 D ActivityManager: setAppIconInfo(), x : 803, y : 879, width : 251, height : 312, isHomeItem : false
 03-03 16:48:59.704  2993  3628 I ActivityManager: Config changes=480 {0 1.0 themeSeq = 0 showBtnBg = 0 206mcc10mnc [pt_BR,fr_BE] ldltr sw360dp w640dp h336dp 480dpi nrml long land finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h appBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1920, 1080) s.21}
 03-03 16:48:59.724  2993  3628 I ActivityManager: Override config changes=480 {0 1.0 themeSeq = 0 showBtnBg = 0 206mcc10mnc [pt_BR,fr_BE] ldltr sw360dp w640dp h336dp 480dpi nrml long land finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h appBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1920, 1080) s.21} for displayId=0
 03-03 16:48:59.762  2993  3314 D ActivityManager: package  com.samsung.android.game.gametools, user - 0 is SDcard whitelisted
 03-03 16:48:59.775  2993  3314 I ActivityManager: Start proc 32163:com.samsung.android.game.gametools/u0a27 for service com.samsung.android.game.gametools/.floatingui.service.external.GameToolsIntentService
 03-03 16:48:59.781  2993  5473 W ActivityManager: crash : com.FarSouth.RocketJumper,0
 03-03 16:48:59.795  2993  5473 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.FarSouth.RocketJumper/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity
 03-03 16:48:59.817  2993  5385 I ActivityManager: DSS on for com.samsung.android.game.gametools and scale is 1.0
 03-03 16:48:59.857  2993  3628 I ActivityManager: Config changes=480 {0 1.0 themeSeq = 0 showBtnBg = 0 206mcc10mnc [pt_BR,fr_BE] ldltr sw360dp w360dp h616dp 480dpi nrml long port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h appBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 1920) s.22}
 03-03 16:48:59.884  2993  3628 I ActivityManager: Override config changes=480 {0 1.0 themeSeq = 0 showBtnBg = 0 206mcc10mnc [pt_BR,fr_BE] ldltr sw360dp w360dp h616dp 480dpi nrml long port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h appBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 1920) s.22} for displayId=0
 03-03 16:48:59.914  2993  3027 I ActivityManager: Showing crash dialog for package com.FarSouth.RocketJumper u0
 03-03 16:48:59.995  2993  5329 D PackageManager: getSelectedMetaData : packageName(com.FarSouth.RocketJumper) or Metadata strings {[Ljava.lang.String;@b99c7e3}
 03-03 16:49:00.307  2993  3026 W ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{f3e35f2 u0 com.FarSouth.RocketJumper/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t21599 f}
 03-03 16:49:00.313  2993  3026 D ActivityManager: isScaleDownAnimationEnabled() : true
 03-03 16:49:00.313  2993  3026 D ActivityManager: clearAppIconInfo()
 03-03 16:49:00.313  2993  3026 D ActivityManager: applyOptionsLocked, ANIM_CUSTOM_SCALE_DOWN
 03-03 16:49:00.343  2993  5329 D ActivityManager: post active user change for 0 fullscreen true isHomeActivity() true
```

I don't have any experience with crash logs but it seems that its either Android Game Tools or Unity Player Activity that's crashing my game? Before adding the GPGS to my game it worked normally. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I know that GPGS let your game crash with an IllegalStateException if you don't set its ID. I assume that's the case here, although I can't see it in your log.

Comment: How could I check this?

Comment: You need the crash log, set your Logcat output filtering to something that you can see it.

Answer (score 0):

dou you have Admob SDK in your game? GPGS and Admob did not work well together. Maybe use a older Version of GPGS the newest version makes often problems.

Comment: Yes, I have AdMob, how would I downgrade the GPGS version? If you please could shed some light, I'd appreciate